# Update changed properties from store

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

I load data to a datagrid using a simple linq query, with the `.ToList()` method, (I have to do so because it doesn't bind to a grid otherwise)

My questions is how can I refresh that list without reloading all records, only those who have been modified in the store (msSQL server), that could be based on the identity key or date stamp. often only 1 or 2 records were updated, so I don't need to update all 1000 records in the list.

Comment: Why would you have 1000 rows in a datagrid?  Rule of thumb is only show 300 or less to user, and make sure you use paging.  If you went this route you would could rerun the query when user select Refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to query the database for the changes even if its one or two records.

You could have a refresh button, which could query the database for a given list of IDs (in your datagrid) and return  only the ones that were updated since you performed the last query (via timestamp column), then update the rows in the datagrid which matches the IDs which have changes.

Comment: I can't change that part.. the users are used to search with devexpress auto filter, which only works if all rows are on one page. [I did try thier server mode, but its kind of slow for the amount of records i usually have]

Comment: Then you will need to call gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
Or  Implementing Notification Behavior 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument754